# Where is the information about the authors for articles stored?

Tags: users, author, multi-author

I have recently been appointed to maintain a Wordpress powered news site. I don't have much experience with wordpress and have been teaching myself as I go. The site I am maintaining was recently migrated to a new wordpress site. While the old site used the standard mechanism for storing authors, the new site uses the Co-author's Plus Plugin.

After the migration, all of the articles are shown as written by "admin." I'm sure the information about the authors is stored somewhere in the database, just the website does not know to look for that information. Can someone tell me where I can find this information so I can then proceed to add it through the Co-Authors plus plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Post authors are stored in the `wp_posts` table under the `post_author` column. Check the [database description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_posts). The author in that table is stored as an ID number which references the ID in the [`wp_users` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_users). Additional user information is kept in [the `wp_usermeta` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_usermeta).

I have no idea what you may have to do to get that synced up with the plugin.